# Send Email Notification when the SharePoint item modified

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, flow, power-automate

I am having an issue sending email notifications when the item has been modified. I have an SP online list of two columns. The first column is a choice field called job status and has In-Progress and Completed options. The second column is multiple lines of text called comments.

When the job status columns field change from in-progress to completed the creator will receive the notification that your job has been completed.

My issue is the Marketing team wants to go back to the list and add some comments even after the job status has been changed to complete. And the moment they add some words, the creator will receive another email about the job status that has been changed to complete.

Would you please help me to make sure the email is only sent once? I am using SP online, and Power automate.

Answer (score 2):

Follow below approach:

1. Add one more column in list say "Is Email Sent?" (Choice column with Yes & No options or simply Yes/No column) >> Set default value to No >> Hide column from list forms.
2. In Power Automate, add Condition action to check if this column is set to "No" >> In If Yes/true block, send an email and update same item & set column value to "Yes".
3. This way, if Power Automate flow runs again, above column will have value "Yes". So, the email sending action will not be executed & user will not receive the notification again.

Comment: Hi @Harris does this help you? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.